# MySQL/PHP Selecting and counting from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not even sure this is possible... I'll show you what I'm working with, then what I would like to do:

**state:**

```
state_id
```

**town:**

```
town_id
state_id
misc_property
```

**street:**

```
street_id
town_id
state_id
```

These are set up in a hierarchy.

**What I want to select:**

I would like to select all towns with a misc_property, while at the same time selected the state it belongs to and counting all of the streets in that town.

This is what I have so far:

```
$sql="SELECT 
    a.state_id AS state_id, 
    b.town_id AS town_id, 
    COUNT(c.street_id) 

    FROM 
    state a, 
    town b, 
    street c 

    WHERE 
    b.misc_property='$property'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT
    town.state_id AS state_id,
    town.town_id AS town_id,
    COUNT(street.street_id) AS count
FROM
    state INNER JOIN town ON state.state_id = town.state_id 
    LEFT JOIN street ON town.town_id = street.town_id
GROUP BY
    state_id,
    town_id
HAVING
    town.misc_property = 'stuff';
```

Comment: good solution, bt should'nt JOIN be LEFT join rather than INNER join? because there may exist a town without street entry. (ofcourse its more of business logic). but am just commenting in the current question's context. cheers..!

Comment: What if I needed to grab something from the state besides the id?

Comment: I added the state to the joins. You can now put columns from the state table in the select section.

Comment: Thank you. I removed state_id in the GROUP BY. Not sure why that was needed. For some reason in the HAVING clause town.misc_property was not accepted until i put in the SELECT clause town.misc_property AS misc_property. if you have any thoughts, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GROUP BY town_id with HAVING for special WHERE conditions

Answer (score 0):

Use joins:

```
SELECT * FROM state
LEFT JOIN town ON state.state_id = town.state_id
LEFT JOIN street ON street.town_id = town.town_id
WHERE town.misc_property = '$property'
```

Comment: You're not counting the streets.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. Yup, your query seems to be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$sql="SELECT 
    a.state_id AS state_id, 
    b.town_id AS town_id, 
    Select COUNT(c.street_id) From C Where C.town_id = b.town_id 

    FROM 
    state a, 
    town b, 
    street c 

    WHERE 
    b.misc_property='$property'and b.state_id = a.state_id "
```

Comment: You should join the tables, not subquery them.

Comment: yeah join is better but just to make it simple on edit his code